# Homework help with statistics

Tags: statistics

I have just answered a question and i am not to sure whether i have got it correct or if i have missed something.

Question:
Suppose that X and Y are independent random variables, with N(-2,2) and N(10,3) distributions, respectively. State the distributions of the 3 random variables -X, Y-X-5, (X+Y)/2.

My Solution:
-X~N(-1(-2),$ (-1)^2 $(2))

-X~N(2,2)

.................

Y-X-5~N(1(-2)+(-1)(10)-5, 1^2(2)+(-1)^2(3)-5)

Y-X-5~N(-17,0)

.................

(X+Y)/2~N(4,1.25)

Comment: variance=0 is it realistic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and third are correct. The second is however not correct. In the second, it seems that you're calculating with $-Y$ instead of $Y$. Instead it should be:
$$Y-X-5\sim\mathcal{N}(10-(-2)-5,3+(-1)^2\cdot2)=\mathcal{N}(7,5).$$

Comment: The last one seems correct or not? if you multiply a rv. with a constant, its variance is scaled with the square of it.

Comment: Thanks. With the second i completely did not notice the Y and X had changed around. With the 3rd one though i came to that solution through using 1/2.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: Yes, you're totally right. I read his solution as  a mean of $4.1$ and a variance of $25$. Sorry.